# Secure Authentication using Digital Certificate and Digital Signature

Tags: ssl, certificate, digital-signature, pki

I am developing authentication through the PKI. I am new to authenticate the user through the PKI so after reading on internet i came up with this solution. A user will create a public and private key. To validate the public key the user will apply for the Digital Certificate. The Digital certificate will have the public key, the meta data of the user and the Digital Signature of the Certificate Authority. To prove no data tampering the user will use the Digital Signature which will be the hash of the certificate with the private key of the user. The user will send both the Digital Certificate, Digital Signature and the data to the server.

The server in response verify the Digital Certificate and grab the public key to validate the Digital Signature and after verification the Server will encrypt the data using Public key and send to the user. I am also using https for the secure transfer of the information.

Now I am confuse how this will be done pragmatically.

1. From where I can get the Digital Certificate, majorly which are the trustful CA ?
2. Is there any REST API by the Certificate Authority where I send the certificate to validate a certificate?
3. Is there any library to parse the certificate to extract the information?

Sorry I am newbie in the Digital Certificate and Digital Signature.

Comment: Are you looking to Auth WebLogin or API ?

Comment: You need to apply for Digital Certificate with CA in your country. Refer to their website for procedure.

Regarding Lib, depending on platform you may use .NET System.Security.* or BouncyCastle is available for both Java and .NET platforms.

Comment: Thanks Baharat, my question is not the same as you mentioned. It would be great if you can answer the questions mentioned as your purpose answer is of same filed but dont fulfill what i asked

Comment: I am looking for REST API and want to know from where one can get the Certificate and is it psossible to verify it through REST API from CA

Comment: In which country you are looking for Certificate?  I have not heard of verifying certificate using REST API form CA but Certificate has OSCP (Online Certificate Status Protocol) or (CRL) Certificate revocation list. Please research on above two topics...

Comment: Germany, Yes I am confuse how to verify the certificate. I will check the above topic

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193325/discussion-between-uahmed-and-bharat-vasant).

Comment: You may refer to my asnwer to question User Authentication from Browser using Digital Signature Certificate on USB Token or Smart Card at https://stackoverflow.com/a/55757349/9659885

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To prove no data tampering the user will use the Digital Signature which will be the hash of the certificate with the private key of the user.

No, the digital signature is generated over the message data using the private key. The certificate is used to verify it

> The server in response verify the Digital Certificate and grab the public key to validate the Digital Signature and after verification the Server will encrypt the data using Public key and send to the user. I am also using https for the secure transfer of the information.

- you should associate the public key to the user account during registration process
- with https, additional encryption is redundant and useless
- encryption with public key (assuming RSA) is limited to key size.

> From where I can get the Digital Certificate, majorly which are the trustful CA ?

Each browser has its own trusted list. Additionally in EU exists a list of qualified certificate providers. The lists are different.

You can also build your own CA

> Is there any REST API by the Certificate Authority where I send the certificate to validate a certificate?

the message format to request a certificate is standardized (pkcs # 10), but the connection protocol with the CA is not. It is possible that a CA has REST services, but in any case, a certificate will never be issued by the CA without validating the user data that is included in the certificate

> Is there any library to parse the certificate to extract the information?

Of course, search for your programming language

Comment: Thank you for the detail reply. Things are getting way clear to me. I check this video and it says that Digital Signature is the hash of the certificate https://youtu.be/LRMBZhdFjDI?t=293 so are we talking about two different digital signatures?

Comment: I think you're mixing concepts. A certificate has an embedded digital signature made with the private key of the CA root certificate (which is done over the hash of the certificate) to prove that it has been issued by that CA. But a digital signature made with users's private key is performed with the message hash, note with the certificate hash. To prove that a message has not been tampered it is needed to apply a digital signature over that message.